Can the Super-Spartans analogy work to disprove functionalism?
It seems like it does!
We have input sure but the output? it doesn't apply here. Also the analogy seems to be begging the question, because it just assumes that they are in pain without defining why, and we are interested in knowing how to know or define that they are in pain or not.

This question could be greatly improved by explaining what the "Super-Spartans analogy" actually is, for those not already familiar with it.

In the hypothetical super-Spartans scenario, there is a world of people who show no outward reaction to pain, despite inwardly feeling it and thinking about it.
Functionalism does not generally say that mental phenomena depend on outward reactions; they depend on the functional relationships between the different parts inside the brain. So it is not necessary under functionalism for the super-Spartans to outwardly display signs of pain, for them to feel pain. It is enough for them to inwardly process and think about the pain.

Okay but it seems Functionalism is just pushing the question, or it says that if they are in pain then they are in pain, which is obviously true but how is it helpful to call that a theory?

@ura If the parts of their brain are functionally interacting in the "pain" way, they're in pain. It's not just "if they are in pain they are in pain" - it ties the subjective pain to the physical, functional interactions.
